# Backbone tests returning timeout

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, mocha.js

I am getting a `timeout of 2000ms exceeded` message when running the following tests for my Backbone application.

How can I get this test to pass?
I am also trying to listen for the event's being triggered when calling `more`. How could this be tested?

```
describe("Foo.Collection.Items/Discover", function () {
    describe("More method", function () {

        beforeEach(function () {

            this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

            this.hasLength = sinon.spy(Foo.View.ItemFeed.prototype, "toggleFeedback");
            this.noLength = sinon.spy(Foo.View.ItemFeed.prototype, "stopLazyload");

            this.item1 = new Foo.Model.item({
                description: "A swell minions movie!",
                for_sale: false,
                title: "Minions: Goldfinger",
                link: "/discover",
                'private': false,
                'main_image': false
            });

            this.item2 = new Foo.Model.item({
                description: "A round pot",
                for_sale: true,
                title: "Pot",
                link: "/discover",
                'private': true,
                'main_image': true
            });

            this.itemsDiscover = new Foo.Collection.Items([this.item1, this.item2], {url: "/discover"});

        });

        afterEach(function () {

            this.server.restore();
            this.hasLength.restore();
            this.noLength.restore();

        });

        it("should fetch items and trigger moreFetched", function (done) {


            this.server.respondWith('GET', "/discover", [
                200,
                {"Content-type": "application/json"},
                JSON.stringify([this.item1, this.item2])
            ]);

            this.itemsDiscover.once("add", function () {
                expect(this.itemsDiscover).to.have.length(2);
                expect(this.hasLength).to.be.calledOnce();

                done();
            });

            this.itemsDiscover.more();

        });
    });
});
```

The part of the Backbone `Collection` I am trying to test:

```
more: function () {
    var collection = this;
    this.fetch({
        success: function (collection, response) {
            if (response.length) {
                collection.trigger('moreFetched');
            } else {
                collection.trigger('emptyFetched');
            }
        },
        reset: false,
        remove: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Whenever I have this problem it's usually the result of the URL that `fetch()` uses isn't actually what I'm mocking out via the `sinon.fakeServer`.  What URL do you see if you manually call `this.itemsDiscover.url()`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the value when running tests so I just did a  console.log(this.itemsDiscover.url()) and got the following message when I ran the tests:`TypeError: '/discover' is not a function (evaluating 'this.itemsDiscover.url()')`.

Comment: Does this mean that the right URL is being used?

Comment: in your case is `this.itemsDiscover.url` because you use "url" property as string not a function http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url

Comment: Thanks @IvanFraixedes ! The URL that is logged is `/discover`

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have an exception that avoids to call `done`, try

```
this.itemsDiscover.once("add", function () {
  try {
    expect(this.itemsDiscover).to.have.length(2);
    expect(this.hasLength).to.be.calledOnce();
    done();
  } catch(e) {
    done(e);
  }
});
```

If you get an error then post it, because I think what it is.

Comment: That's a good thought -- once I read that I assumed it would be the issue.  Error handling in tests is an easy thing to miss.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's going on:  your test method is dependent on the `add` event being triggered in order to get into the callback that verifies the data.  However, the way you've set up `this.itemsDiscover`, it contains `this.item1` and `this.item2` already:

```
....
this.itemsDiscover = new Foo.Collection.Items([this.item1, this.item2], {url: "/discover"});
```

Then, your mocking out of the URL will also return the string version of an array containing `this.item1` and `this.item2`:

```
...
this.server.respondWith('GET', "/discover", [
            200,
            {"Content-type": "application/json"},
            JSON.stringify([this.item1, this.item2])
        ]);
...
```

Here's the kicker:  the `add` event will never be fired by the collection, because the two items returned *already exist* in the collection.  D'oh.

I suggest changing the test to wait for a `sync` event instead, which is always fired after a successful `fetch`:

```
this.itemsDiscover.once("sync", function () {
    expect(this.itemsDiscover).to.have.length(2);
    expect(this.hasLength).to.be.calledOnce();

    done();
});
```

I expect that will get your test code running.

Comment: Thanks for answer Peter. However I still get the timeout error.

Comment: After bashing my head against the wall I suddenly realised that I cam missing `this.server.autoRespond = true` in the build-up, so logically the server was never returning a response! Big D'OH on my part!

Comment: Ah -- that'll do it.  Hope the rest of the discussion helped.

Comment: Definitely Peter. I appreciate the help and the time taking.